# Changing Vuetify's Button Width And Padding

Tags: css, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Buttons are large and going over the card width
[image]

This should be easy, but I'm having a bit of tough time customizing the buttons inside the cards. I want to remove all the padding, so that the black border nicely encompasses the icon without any extra space in the left/right-hand sides. I've tried adding custom css and `!important` and directly overriding the `div.btn__content`, but those don't work. Any ideas to do this as simply as possible?

Reproduction [Link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aVLBLG)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is the `min-width` of the `.btn` class. Setting that to `0` will allow the button to be smaller than `88px`. You should also just set the `padding` of the `.btn__content` to `0`.

```
div.btn__content {
  padding: 0;
}

div.card__actions .btn {
  min-width: 0;
}
```

[Here's an updated codepen.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QOqzJX)

Answer (score 7):

For newer versions of Vuetify (1.2.4 and above) you need to use this:

```
/* turn off min-width for all buttons */
.v-btn {
  min-width: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change min-width of `.btn` class and set `padding-left: 16px` of `.btn-content`.

Here is an example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zPEyLB

Answer (score 1):

You might have to use `::v-deep`

```
::v-deep .v-btn {
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
}
```