# How to change v-btn size

Tags: html, vue.js, button, vuetify.js

Goal:
I am refactoring Vue components to be more customisable and one of the things we need is to be able to pass in a size value and have that reflect in our button component. Project uses Vuetify.

Old Code:

```
<v-btn
  @click.prevent="clicked"
  :class="some-classes"
  fluid
  block
  large
  elevation="6"
>
  {{ title }}
</v-btn>
```

I want to remove that "large" and switch to relying on either a size attribute or a classname. The button should retain its current styling, most importantly that `height=44px`. I have tried the following (they are hardcoded at the moment just to see if these changes will actually influence the style):

Option 1 (copying the docs):

```
<v-btn
  @click.prevent="clicked"
  :class="some-classes"
  fluid
  block
  size="large" <<< SIZE ATTRIBUTE
  elevation="6"
>
  {{ title }}
</v-btn>
```

Option 1 does not work. It does not look as big as the button used to look. Upon inspection, the button is only 36px high and has class `v--size-default`.

Option 2:

```
<v-btn
  @click.prevent="clicked"
  :class="some-classes v--size-large" <<< CLASS
  fluid
  block
  elevation="6"
>
  {{ title }}
</v-btn>
```

Option 2 does not do anything visually. Upon inspection, it has `v--size-default` followed by `v--size-large` but the button itself still just has height 36px.

What am I missing? Also curious what is the difference between an attribute like "large" that just sits in the tag body, by itself vs. something of the form attr=value. What is that called and how is it different? THANKS!

Comment: Vuetify 2 and 3 has major differenences in component props and slots. It seems like you are migrating from vuetify 2 to 3 (not sure :)). If you specify the versions of the library used, it will more more helpful for peoples to answer your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing Vuetify's Button Width And Padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47331310/changing-vuetifys-button-width-and-padding)

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, setting size via the [:size](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-btn/#props-size) prop seems to work, have a look at the snippet:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()
const app = {
  setup(){
    return {
      size: ref('default'),
      sizes: ref(['x-small', 'small', 'default', 'large', 'x-large'])
    }
  }

}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main class="d-flex">
      <v-radio-group v-model="size">
        <v-radio v-for="sizeName in sizes" :key="sizeName" :label="sizeName" :value="sizeName"></v-radio>
      </v-radio-group>

      <div class="ma-4 flex-grow-1">
        <v-btn fluid block elevation="6" :size="size">
          Button
        </v-btn>
      </div>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

As to you second question, props with a boolean value are set to true if they are given without value, i.e. just `large` is read as `:large="true"`. Vue calls it [boolean casting](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#boolean-casting), the idea is that you can use them like regular HTML attributes like `readonly`, `disabled`, `checked` etc.

---

If the `:size` prop is not working, my guess is that you are using Vue/Vuetify 2, where it does not exist. But you can transform an input like `small` or `large` to input props using `v-bind`. Assuming you have a variable `size`, you can do:

```html
<v-btn
  v-bind="{
    [size]: true
  }"
  ...
/>
```

If you have invalid values (like `default`) or if `size` can be empty, you can use a computed property to build the object for `v-bind`. Something like:

```
computed:{
  buttonProps(){
    return this.size && this.size !== 'default' ? {[this.size]: true} : {}
  }
}
```

Here is another snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data(){
   return {
      size: 'default',
      sizes: ['x-small', 'small', 'default', 'large', 'x-large', null]
    }
  },
  computed:{
    buttonProps(){
      return this.size && this.size !== 'default' ? {[this.size]: true} : {}
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.v-main__wrap{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        <v-radio-group v-model="size">
            <v-radio v-for="sizeName in sizes" :key="sizeName" :label="sizeName" :value="sizeName"></v-radio>
          </v-radio-group>

          <div class="ma-4 flex-grow-1">
            Props: {{buttonProps}}
            <v-btn fluid block elevation="6" v-bind="buttonProps">
              Button
            </v-btn>
          </div>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: This a very comprehensive answer, thank you! The only thing that worked for me was `large="true" or large="false"` which is not as flexible as I would like (basically just toggles between large and default). But if someone else upvotes this answer then I will accept it as the right answer.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! Are you using Vue 2? Have a look at the updated answer

Comment: This works as shown in Vue 2, I had no idea about this, thank you